# after ajax request my function call its not working properly, just works after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a list of images. Each image have a link to delete it:

```
echo '<a class="delete j_bannerdelete" id="'.$result_banner['id'].'" href="#">Delete</a> ';
```

And Im deleting this images with jQuery Ajax.

But when I have just one image I wan to hide this "Delete" link.

So in my js file, the first thing I have inside my `$(function(){});` is:

```
hidelink(1); //my function to hide if I have only 1 image
```

And it is working fine, when I acess my page If I have only one image my "Delete" link dont appears.

But  when I have my two last images and I click to delete one, when I click to delete I wan to hide my "Delete" link in that momment, and its not working, just works when I refresh the page.

Do you see why this is happening?

My code to delete a image is this:

```
$(function(){
    var banid = null;
    $("a#nao").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.confirm').fadeOut("slow",function(){
            $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("slow"); 
        });
        $('.bannerli li[id="'+ banid +'"]').css('background','#f5f5f5');
        banid = null;
    });
    $("a#delete").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!banid) return;
        $.post(url,{action:'delete',id: banid},function(){
            window.setTimeout(function(){
                $('.bannerli li[id="'+ banid +'"]').fadeOut("slow");
            },500);
            $('.confirm').fadeOut("fast",function(){
                $('.delete_dialog').fadeOut("fast"); 
            });
            hidelink(2); //here I call my function every time I delete

        });

    });
    $('.bannerli').on('click','.j_bannerdelete',function(){
        banid = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.bannerli li[id="'+ banid +'"]').css('background','red');
        $('.delete_dialog p').text('You really want to remove this image?');
        $('.delete_dialog').fadeIn("slow",function(){
            $('.confirm').fadeIn("slow");
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

This is the hide "Delete" link function:

```
function hidelink($value) {
    if($('.bannerli li').length <= $value) {
        $('.j_bannerdelete').hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're just fading them out not deleting them. Try actually removing them.

Answer (score 0):

On my opinion you must use `.foreach("selectorname")` to find a matching elements if length is `0` then use `.("selectorname").hide()` in order to hide delete link or better add css class that hiding link (so if there images appear again, you'll just remove this css class to show link again).
P.S. And this good if you will add code for handling errors on `$post` call like that one:

```
self.remove = function (item) {
    $.ajax({ type: "DELETE", url: '/api/sets/' + item.ID })
        .done(function () {
            alert("Товар успешно удален!");
        })
     .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
         var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
         alert(err.Message);
     });
}
```